# SAM and SYSTEM file copying to another PC

Tags: encryption, windows

Can I copy a SAM file and a SYSTEM file of a laptop and just change my SAM file and SYSTEM file on my own PC? Will my PC then have the password of the laptop? Or is there another way I can copy the password from one computer to another, without knowing the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, didn't test yet, but I think it's not possible to do it that way.

There are two possible places to store user's password. SAM file and registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESAM`). Both are inaccessible if Windows is running.

Just to understand your question better, why do you want to have the same password in your own PC, if you dont know what it is?

Why don't you run Mimikatz or Pwdump in the laptop, check the cleartext password, and change your own password to the same?

Comment: Because is don't how i need to run Pwdump in the laptop, i did get it from my grandpa and nobody know his password. I only dit get in his pc because of kali linux.

Comment: @Jorrit hmm, ok. So if you can run LIVE CD of Kali Linux on the laptop, you can simple [mount the windows partition](http://www.tecmint.com/how-do-i-access-or-mount-windows-ntfs-partition-in-linux/); navigate to /Windows/System32/config; backup the actual SAM file ("`/usr/bin/cp SAM SAM_backup`"); and use a tool like **chntpw** to reset the user password. like `chntpw -u <user> SAM`. To list the users you can simply use `chntpw -l SAM`

Comment: @Jorrit cool! If my answer helped you please vote up or mark it as correct!  Thank you!